# Laplace transform and Differentiation help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-fractions

I need to know how to differentiate something like these

a) Differentiate with respect to s  $$ b/(s^2 +b^2)$$

b) Solve the given equation 
                               $$f(t) = s(1/s^2 + 2/s^3)$$

c) Reverse Laplace transform of $$(3s - 15)/(2s^2 -4s + 10)$$

Comment: Nitpick: $s(\frac{1}{s^2} + \frac{2}{s^3}) isn't an equation because it doesn't contain an equals sign.  Maybe you mean "simplify the expression."

Comment: Please don't write $3s - \Big(15/(2s^2-4s+10)\Big)$ when you mean $(3s - 15)/(2s^2-4s+10)$.

Comment: @IAmBrianDawkins: You forgot to put a `$` at the end of your equation to properly display your $\TeX$ input.

Comment: Not everyone is a genius like you @Rajesh!

Comment: I do not understand this: a) and b) are *very* elementary while c) is not at all elementary (since the concept of LT is not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Quotient Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule). You have

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{ds} \biggl[\frac{b}{s^{2}+b^{2}}\biggr] &= \frac{(s^{2}+b^{2})\cdot \frac{d}{ds}(b) - b \cdot \frac{d}{ds}(s^{2}+b^{2})}{(s^{2}+b^{2})^{2}} \\ &=  \frac{-2\cdot b \cdot s}{(s^{2}+b^{2})^{2}}
\end{align*}

As for (b) just multiply $s$ inside the brackets and you get $$\frac{1}{s}+\frac{2}{s^2} = \frac{s+2}{s^{2}}$$

Comment: hahahaha . . . dumb moments today! thanks a lot. I had been stuck on those for hours. What about the last one there

Comment: happens to everyone. Maybe tommorow could be mine :)

Comment: So in (b), you didn't mean "solve the equation" at all.  You meant simplify the expression.  It would be easier to understand you if you said what you meant.

Answer (score 5):

For c),
$$
\frac{{3s - 15}}{{2s^2  - 4s + 10}} = \frac{3}{2}\frac{{s - 5}}{{s^2  - 2s + 5}} = \frac{3}{2}\frac{{s - 1 - 4}}{{(s - 1)^2  + 4}} = \frac{3}{2}\frac{{s - 1}}{{(s - 1)^2  + 2^2}} - 3\frac{2}{{(s - 1)^2  + 2^2 }}.
$$
Now let $\alpha = -1$ and $\omega = 2$, and consider 8-9 of [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms).

EDIT: By 9 and 8 of that table, the inverse transforms of $\frac{{s + \alpha }}{{(s + \alpha )^2  + \omega ^2 }}$ and  $\frac{\omega}{{(s + \alpha)^2  + \omega^2 }}$ are $e^{-\alpha t} \cos(\omega t)$ and $e^{-\alpha t} \sin (\omega t)$, respectively. Hence the inverse transform of $\frac{{3s - 15}}{{2s^2  - 4s + 10}}$ is 
$$
\frac{3}{2}e^t \cos (2t) - 3e^t \sin (2t).
$$

Comment: @ Shai: Great job. Just have one problem following along of where the -$3$ came from on the second fraction $\mapsto$ $-3\dfrac{2}{(s-1)^2+2^2}$.

Comment: @night owl: Consider $\frac{3}{2}( - 4) =  - 3 \cdot 2$. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

As for (c), first of all, get rid of that $2$ factor in the denominator: $2s^2 -4s +10 = 2(s^2 -2s +5)$ and observe that the polynomial $s^2 -2s +5$ has no real roots. So, we write it as follows:

$$
s^2 -2s + 5 = (s-1)^2 + (5 - 1) = (s-1)^2 + 2^2
$$

Next, we try to decompose our fraction like this:

$$
\frac{3s-15}{(s-1)^2 + 2^2} = A \frac{s-1}{(s-1)^2 + 2^2} + B \frac{2}{(s-1)^2 + 2^2} \ ,
$$

for some constants $A$ and $B$ which you'll have no trouble to find.

Why do we do this? Well, because we have listen to what our professor said in classroom and we *know* that each member on the right-hand side has an easy inverse Laplace transform.   :-)

Namely,

$$
{\cal L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{2} \frac{3s-15}{(s-1)^2 + 2^2} \right\} = \frac{A}{2} {\cal L}^{-1} \left\{ \frac{s-1}{(s-1)^2 + 2^2} \right\} + \frac{B}{2} {\cal L}^{-1} \left\{ \frac{2}{(s-1)^2 + 2^2} \right\}
$$

Which means

$$
{\cal L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{2} \frac{3s-15}{(s-1)^2 + 2^2} \right\} = \frac{A}{2} e^t \cos (2t) + \frac{B}{2} e^t \sin (2t)
$$

Comment: Perhaps you meant $\frac{{s - 1}}{{(s - 1)^2  + 2^2 }}$ instead of $\frac{{s}}{{(s - 1)^2  + 2^2 }}$?

Comment: Oh, yes. You're right. Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** This is an extensive edit to Shai Covo's answer.

---

For part ( **C** ) it is the following:

Pulling out a factor of $2$ from the denominator and the constant multiple of $3$ from the numerator leads to: $$ \frac{{3s - 15}}{{2s^2 - 4s + 10}} = \frac{3}{2}\frac{{s - 5}}{{s^2 - 2s + 5}} $$

Next we do Completing the Square for the polynomial $(s^2-2s+5)~$ in the denominator and re-writing the numerator constant $-5$ as $(-1-4)$ giving us:

$$ = \frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{{s - 1 - 4}}{{(s - 1)^2 + 4}} $$

Let denominator equal $K$.

Separating the fraction into parts with them being $\dfrac{3}{2}\cdot\dfrac{(s-1)}{K}$ and $-3\cdot\dfrac{2}{K}$; after distributing the $\dfrac{3}{2}$ to the second term $-4$. This leads to the expression below now.

$$ =\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{{(s - 1)}}{{(s - 1)^2 + 2^2}} - 3\cdot\frac{2}{{(s - 1)^2 + 2^2 }}. $$ Now notice that $a = 1$ and $b = 2$. To see this, take a look at this table of Laplace Transforms for the form $e^{at} \cos(b t)$ and $e^{at} \sin (b t)$ located here $\longmapsto$ [Table of $\mathcal Laplace~Transforms$](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf) .

From the table of transforms, the inverse transform of $\dfrac{s-a }{(s-a )^2 + b ^2 }~$ and $~\dfrac{b}{{(s-a)^2 + b^2 }}$

are $e^{at} \cos(bt)$ and $e^{at} \sin (bt)$, respectively.

Hence the inverse laplace transform of our original problem is, $$ \mathcal{L^{-1}} \left\{ \dfrac{{3s - 15}}{{2s^2 - 4s + 10}} \right\} = \frac{3}{2}e^{t} \cos(2t) - 3e^{t} \sin(2t). $$

Hope this helps out.

Good~Luck

Answer (score -2):

I'm going to GUESS that in (c), you really meant $(3s-15)/(2s^2-4s-10)$, despite the fact that you wrote $3s-\Big(15/(2s^2-4s-10)\Big)$.

The quadratic polynomial $2s^2-4s-10$ is $0$ when $s=1\pm\sqrt{6}$, so it factors as $2(s-1-\sqrt{6})(s-1+\sqrt{6})$.  Then you can do a partial-fraction decomposition as
$$
\frac{3s-15}{2s^2-4s-10} = \frac{A}{s-1-\sqrt{6}} + \frac{B}{s-1+\sqrt{6}}.
$$
You need to figure out numbers what $A$ and $B$ are.

Then find the inverse Laplace transform of each of the two terms separately.

**Later edit:**  Oh.  I see you had $+10$, not $-10$.  So the quadratic is irreducible.  But you should still find it useful to bear this kind of thing in mind.  I see that two others went through partial fractions without mentioning the term "partial fractions".  And they completed the square without mentioning the term "completing the square".